# Trouble adding Silverlight 3.0 control to existing ASP.NET project

Tags: c#, asp.net, silverlight, silverlight-3.0

So I'm ready to add my Silverlight control to my existing ASP.NET web application. I'm finding it really hard to make sense of some of the stuff I'm finding off of Google. (This is due to  both my inexperience with SL and MS removing the SL ASP tag.)

If anyone has any simple, clear-cut instructions on how I can get things going, please help. Thank you.

UPDATE: So I've got it working, in part. I added the necessary code to a user control ascx but it isn't appearing on the page for some reason. (Though it worked on the test pages and works when I add it directly to the page.)

Also, for some reason, it only appears once the mouse hovers over it... ?

Answer (score 0):

> Also, for some reason, it only appears once the mouse hovers over it

Check to make sure that you don't have a zero value (a default value by the design surface) in anything like maxwidth or minwidth.